# Parsing special date format with GSON

Tags: android, json, datetime, gson

I'm trying to parse some JSON using Gson. The dates in the data look like this:

```
09/08/14 10:20:31
```

(I suspect it's the British Format, the documentation is not clear on anything)

Gson complained that the String `"09/08/14 10:20:31"` cannot be parsed to a date, so I took the advice of some other question and used this:

```
    gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss").create();
```

However, when I use this, I get some other error:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09/08/14" (at offset 2)
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:555)
```

All I need is a simple way to parse this date format, I don't want to spend days figuring out serialization stuff.

Comment: try `toString()` then `Substring` the pieces out, then assemble your own date object from those pieces.

Comment: in the exception, the date you are trying to parse, doesnt have a time stamp... So the parsing would fail as it expects one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the date format `"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"`

However your exception is:

```
 Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09/08/14" (at offset 2)
```

The date being parsed in the exception does not contain a time stamp. So it is unable to parse it.

Comment: Is there a way to make the time part optional or do I really have to write a serializer for this?

Comment: @LambdaDusk That i am unsure of, you could try making the parser just `dd/MM/yy` and hopefully it ignores the extra